# VHDL Shift Register

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am refreshing my VHDL programming skills (by using ModelSim), I wrote a Shift register project.
There is a problem, that I can't understand what should I do.

The problem is **Q_out<=ACC;** :when I wrote Q_out<=ACC inside the process, the data passed to Q_out at when the clk is going down, When i wrote  **Q_out<=ACC;** after the process ended - Q_out changed when the clk is going up (as it meant to be) but at my test bench I see X instead of '1'...

what did I do wrong?
VHDL CODE:

```
Library ieee;
Use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
Use work.New_Data_Pack.all;

Entity Shift_Reg IS
port(
    Rst,Clk :IN std_logic;
    Data :IN byte; -- std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    Sel :IN t_shift; --sample, shl, shr, rotl, rotr
    Q_out :OUT byte

);

End Shift_Reg;

ARCHITECTURE Shift_Reg_arc OF Shift_Reg IS
Signal ACC: byte:=(OTHERS=>'0'); -- std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
BEGIN

ShiftPro:PROCESS (Rst,Clk)
BEGIN
    IF Rst='1' Then
        Q_out<=(OTHERS=>'0');
        ACC<=(OTHERS=>'0');
        
    ELSIF Clk'EVENT and Clk='1' THEN
        CASE Sel is
            WHEN sample=>
                ACC<=Data;
            WHEN shl=>
                ACC<= ACC (6 downto 0) & '0'; -- & concatenation
            WHEN shr=>
                ACC<='0' & ACC (7 downto 1);  

            WHEN rotl=>
                ACC<=ACC (6 downto 0)& ACC(7);

            WHEN rotr=>
                ACC<=ACC(0) & ACC(7 downto 1);
            WHEN OTHERS=>
                NULL;
        END CASE;

    END IF;
 
--Q_out<=ACC;
End PROCESS;
Q_out<=ACC;
End Shift_Reg_arc;
```

**Test Bench:**

```
Library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
Use work.New_Data_Pack.all;

ENTITY Shift_Reg_TB IS END;

ARCHITECTURE Shift_Reg_TB_arc OF Shift_Reg_TB IS
---DUT Componenet Declaration
COMPONENT Shift_Reg
port(
    Rst,Clk :IN std_logic;
    Data :IN byte; -- std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    Sel :IN t_shift; --sample, shl, shr, rotl, rotr
    Q_out :OUT byte);
END COMPONENT;
-----Signal Declaration----
SIGNAL S_Clk,S_Rst :std_logic:='0';
SIGNAL S_Data, S_Q_out : byte;
SIGNAL S_Sel : t_shift;
SIGNAL S_Run :std_logic:='1';
BEGIN
-----DUT installation----
DUT: Shift_Reg
Port Map(S_Rst, S_Clk, S_Data, S_Sel, S_Q_out);

-----Signal Wave Creation----
S_Rst<='1' after 0ns, '0' after 80 ns;
S_Run<= '1' after 0ns, '0' after 600 ns;
S_Sel<= sample, shl after 150 ns, shr after 250 ns,sample after 350 ns, rotl after 450 ns, rotr after 550 ns;
S_Data<=X"45" after 0ns;--, "10" after 125 ns, "33" after 620 ns, x"44" after 720 ns;

---CLK Creation---------
S_Clk_Create:Process
        BEGIN
         while S_Run='1' loop
        S_clk<='1', '0' after 50 ns;
            Wait for 100 ns;
        END LOOP;
        S_clk<='1';
        Wait;
END PROCESS;
END Shift_Reg_TB_arc;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have conflicting drivers for `Q_out`.  Either it must be driven sequentially by the process, or it is driven concurrently and can never be driven by the process.  But right now you have both a concurrent assignment outside the process:

```
Q_out<=ACC;
```

and a sequential assignment inside the process

```
IF Rst='1' Then
    Q_out<=(OTHERS=>'0');
```

You must delete the in-process reset when you move the clocked update outside the process.